# How to know the system account user that will execute the hooks of a GIT repository?

Tags: git, githooks, rm

Let's say we have this Git repository with path `/home/derp/projects/example.git`. This repository has a **post-receive** hook `/home/derp/projects/example.git/hooks/post-receive` which allows *derp* (git owner) to remove files from other location when someone pushes to it.

#### post-receive

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`
  if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    git --work-tree=/home/derp/outputs/example/ checkout -f $branch
    rm /home/derpina/Pictures/*.jpg
  fi
done
```

Let's just say the **rm** failed because of derp's insufficient privileges. How to know the system account user that will execute the hooks of a GIT repository?

Comment: Try `echo $USER` or `whoami`.

Comment: @ElpieKay do this inside `post-receive`?

Comment: Yes, do it in the hook.

Comment: What remote access method do you use? SSH? Then the hook is executed under the ssh user.